# how to add subviews from array to a uiview?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have my subviews stored in an array...what i want is to place these subviews to my main view  from array....

```
for(int i=0;i<[imageViewArray count];i++)
    {
        NSLog(@" image array count is %d",[imageViewArray count]);
       // countlayers= countlayers+1;
      //  [canvasView insertSubview:[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:countlayers];
        [canvasView addSubview:[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

can you tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: first of all I would recommend using fast enumeration

Comment: what is canvasView? If you want to add image then you can have imageViews on main view on the position where you want to display images/

Comment: please explain your question ?, canvasView is a UIimageView ot Uiview?

Comment: canvasView is a UIView or just take it like self.view
n in my array there are already imageviews with images inside them.
so any solution.

n about fast enumeration can u give an example for it..i havnt used it yet..thnx

Answer (score 0):

*If* `imageViewArray` really contains initialized views, and if those views already have correct `frame` attributes, you're doing nothing wrong (even though your code could be more elegant).

Also, of course, we have to make sure that canvasView is indeed initialized and visible on the screen. Try setting its backgroundColor to something noticeable:

```
canvasView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Once you are sure the canvasView is actually being displayed, I would suggest using fast enumeration, which makes going through the array nicer, and logging your new subviews to make sure their frames are like you want them.

```
for (UIView *imageView in imageViewArray) //this is fast enumeration. You can get it through code completion by typing forin
{
    NSLog(@"%@", imageView); //let's take a look at the imageView. What is its frame?
    [canvasView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: imageviewArray is an array where there are initialized uiviews to be added to my main view or self.view

Comment: Then try running my code. It won't work any better than yours, but the log output can help us figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Used enumeration to add images on your canvas View using imageViewArray and probably you are also missing with the setting frame of the images.

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in imageViewArray) //enumeration. 
{
    //let's set frame for image view before adding to canvasView
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]; 
    //Also make sure imageView has image or not
    if(imageView.image)
    [canvasView addSubview:imageView];
}
```